# How to import ranges of data one googlesheet to another using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form that saves results to a Columns A:F of a googlesheet (called googlesheet1 in this example). I then need to import *some* of the data from the googlesheet1 to a second sheet (Columns C, D and F from googlesheet1 should go to columns A:C in googlesheet2). Data is manually entered into columns D:M of googlesheet2 and should be copied back to googlesheet1 (into columns I:R) with the row order preserved throughout the entire process.

I have all of this working with a series of `=IMPORTRANGE` formulas - but it's slow and causing lag. Is there a way to do this using a series of Google Apps scripts on the forms/sheets?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your goal and `Data is manually entered into columns D:M of googlesheet2 and should be copied back to googlesheet1 (into columns I:R) with the row order preserved throughout the entire process.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: A bit of context might help googlesheet1 contains information provided by students in a university course, this includes some private information that should be available to the professor but no one else. The name of each student (columns C, D, F) should be copied to spreadsheet2. Junior teaching staff use googlesheet2 to mark attendance for students (columns I:R of googlesheet2). That attendance information needs to be copied back to googlesheet1 so that the professor has attendance information as well  as the full form responses for each student.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, it is required to achieve your goal using 2 individual sample scripts? 1. Copy the columns C, D, and F from "googlesheet1" to "googlesheet2". 2. When columns I and R of "googlesheet2" are edited, those are copied to "googlesheet1". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes - I expect it's probably two scripts (at least)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Yes - I expect it's probably two scripts (at least)`, I think that in this case, it is required to know your expected input and output situations. Because, although I can understand your 1st question, unfortunately, I cannot understand your 2nd question. In the case of `2. When columns I and R of "googlesheet2" are edited, those are copied to "googlesheet1".`, where do you want to copy them? in your question, when I can answer one of 2 questions, I cannot post an answer. Because your question has 2 questions. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: The response in D2 of googlesheet2 should be copied into I2 of googlesheet1, D3 to I3 and so on.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Before I post an answer, I would like to confirm your question. From your replying, I understood that your question is as follows. 1. Copy the columns C, D, and F from "googlesheet1" to "googlesheet2". 2. When columns "D" of "googlesheet2" is edited, you want to copy the value of column "D" to the column "I" of the same row number in "googlesheet1" sheet. 3. You want to request to make 2 scripts for achieving these situation. 4. There are no hidden requests in your question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike that's right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A way to move data from one spreadsheet to another

```
function lfunko() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.testsourceid);
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sshsr = 2;//row where data starts
  const ssher = 20;//row where data ends
  const sshsc = 2;//column where data starts
  const sshec = 8;//column where data ends
  const svs = ssh.getRange(sshsr,sshsc,ssher - sshsr + 1, sshec - sshsc + 1).getValues();
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const dshsr = 4;//row where data starts in dsh
  const dshsc = 4;//column where data start in dsh
  dsh.getRange(dshsr,dshsc,svs.length,svs[0].length).setValues(svs)
}
```

ssh:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |

dsh:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
|  |  |  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
|  |  |  | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
|  |  |  | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
|  |  |  | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
|  |  |  | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
|  |  |  | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
|  |  |  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
|  |  |  | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
|  |  |  | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
|  |  |  | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
|  |  |  | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
|  |  |  | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
|  |  |  | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
|  |  |  | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
|  |  |  | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
|  |  |  | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
|  |  |  | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |

Comment: Thanks! Because the column ranges are discontinuous I need to run this a couple of times, but otherwise this is perfect for my needs (and much snappier than using the =IMPORTRANGE formula)

Comment: It could probably be modified for discontinuous range by using a rangelist